# what does foo() = "test"; do?

Tags: c++, string, assembly

While trying to explore how the compiler handles strings in C++ I tried the following program that compiles and runs w/o errors, but I cannot understand if it changes any memory locations or has any effect on the program flow. It doesn't seem to do anything.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string str = "this is public string\n";

string foo() {
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    foo() = "test";       //  what does this line do
    cout << str << endl;

    char c;
    cin>>c;
    return 0;
}
```

It does generate some assembly instructions but I have no idea what they do.

```
getString() = "test";       //  what does this line do
00007FF68B0D6F1B  lea         rcx,[rbp+0E8h]  
00007FF68B0D6F22  call        getString (07FF68B0D1640h)  
00007FF68B0D6F27  mov         qword ptr [rbp+118h],rax  
00007FF68B0D6F2E  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+118h]  
00007FF68B0D6F35  mov         qword ptr [rbp+120h],rax  
00007FF68B0D6F3C  lea         rdx,[string "test" (07FF68B0E1584h)]  
00007FF68B0D6F43  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+120h]  
00007FF68B0D6F4A  call std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::operator= (07FF68B0D1037h)  
00007FF68B0D6F4F  nop  
00007FF68B0D6F50  lea         rcx,[rbp+0E8h]  
00007FF68B0D6F57  call  std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (07FF68B0D1140h) 
cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: `foo()` returns `string`. That's a temporary. You can assign to the temporary but the effect will get lost afterwards. Temporaries are destroyed at end of full expression (after the next `;`).

Comment: You can make the assignment to temporary "visible" by printing the result of this expression directly: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/852442939b229ea0).

Answer (score 7):

It, essentially, doesn't do anything useful.

The `foo` function returns a *copy* of the string `str`, and you assign to this copy. It's similar to:

```
{
    string temp;
    temp = foo();
    temp = "test";

    // Here the temp object is destructed, and the modifications
    // made to it are lost
}
```

Because the statement doesn't have any observable effect, [the as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) allows the compiler to skip not only the assignment but also the call to `foo` itself.

---

Things would be very different if the `foo` function returned a *reference* to the `str` object:

```
string& foo() {
    return str;
}
```

Because then the assignment would assign to the actual `str` object instead:

```
{
    string& temp_ref = foo();
    temp_ref = "test";  // Really assigns to str
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`foo()` returns a copy of `str`.

```
foo() = "test";
```

This line changes the copy's contents to "test" but does not store it anywhere, so effectively it does nothing.